# Lost of Session variable after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Please help me. This is exotic. I have two completely the same ajax calls.

**ONE**:

```
$(document).on("click", "#Change", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("http://xxx.eu/gamePlay.php", {
        instruction: "change", 
    }, function (data, status) {
       $('#gameBoard').html(data);
    });
```

**SECOND**:

```
$(document).on("click", "#End", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("http://xxx.eu/gamePlay.php", {
        instruction: "end"
    }, function (data, status) {
        $('#gameBoard').html(data);
        ph = 5;
    })
```

**PHP LANDING PAGE (gamePlay.php):**

```
$game = $_SESSION['game'];
$game->generateGuessable();
$currentUser = $_SESSION['user'];
print_r($game);
print_r($user);
...
```

**ERROR:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   generateGuessable() on null in
>   /data/web/virtuals/173042/virtual/www/gamePlay.php:27 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in /data/web/virtuals/173042/virtual/www/gamePlay.php on
>   line 27

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM DESC:**

When I call the first ajax snippet
everything works fine. I got the **$game** variable, but when I call
the second code the
**$game** variable is null. **$user** var is always fine. On the localhost everything works fine. If anyone can point me the right way, I guess I must send him some kind of reward. The only difference between local and remote is that remote runs on php 7. But even if that was the problem. It doesn't explain that once it works and then doesn't with the same code.

There is **session_start()** at the beggining! I wouldn't bother...

**UPDATE**
Sometimes it happens that even the #End click doesn't work. It's like 9/10.

Comment: You didn't post all the relevant code.. like how do you even set `$_SESSION['game']` nor what happens in `gamePlay.php` ?

Comment: what dose mean  ph = 5; in second code js. i thing is problems.

Comment: I cut the code, because its too long and not relevant, since everything works on localhost perfectly. I'm looking for more general solution like what could possibly change at the remote server side. Last thing I tried was rewriting the $.post to $.ajax and setting async: false. But no progress made.

Comment: Guys if you ever look at this post again, know that the problem was actually migrating to php 7. Does php 7 introduce some new way of session handeling? Switching server to 5.6 solved my problem.